# Razor Partial View not Rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

If I use the following Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    // do stuff...

    return PartialView("viewName", navLinks);
}
```

calling the partial view in _Layout.cshtml like this:

```
<div id="categories">
    @{ Html.Action("Menu", "Nav"); }
</div>
```

With the following ASCX partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
    Inherits="ViewUserController<IEnumerable<MyDataType>>" %>

<% foreach(var link in Model) { %>
    <%: Html.Route.Link(link.Text, link.RouteValues) %>
<% } %>
```

everything works fine. Yay.

---

BUT, if I use either of the following RAZOR partial views:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyDataType>

@foreach(var link in Model){
    Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

or...

```
@model IEnumerable<MyDataType>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach(var link in Model){
    Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

I get nothing. there's no exception thrown, I just don't get anything rendered. I know the problem isn't with the controller method (it works just great with the ASCX partial view).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RenderAction` method writes the action directly to the view and returns `void`.
The `Action` method returns the action's contents but doesn't write anything to the view.

Writing `@something` will print the value of `something` to the page.
You cannot write `@Html.RenderAction`, since `RenderAction` doesn't return anything.

Writing `Html.Action(...)` (without `@`) calls the method normally, but doesn't do anything with its return value.

Comment: thank you, a very nice explanation. Undoubtedly, I will refer to this again for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing this:

```
@foreach(var link in Model){
    Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

to this:

```
@foreach(var link in Model){
    @Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

It looks like without the @ the method is being called, but the return value is just being dscarded. Putting the @ causes it to be written in the response.

Comment: @Danny - your suggested change did not render the content.

Comment: Oh, I think I also may have removed your braces from "@{ Html.Action("Menu", "Nav"); }" or changed it to RenderAction instead of Action. Maybe it was a combination of both changes. If not, I'll try again when I get home.

Comment: Yep, I had to do both things - remove the braces "@Html.Action(blah)" and also add the @ in front of "@Html.RouteLink". The first change stops the code is so the return value of Action gets output (RenderAction would also work, but it writes directly to the response).

Comment: Np, glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, Changing the way the it was called from _Layout.cshtml worked...

```
<div id="categories">
    @Html.Action("Menu", "Nav");
</div>
```

It is important to note, that @Html.RenderAction DOES NOT work for me. I'd really love some explanation here, because right now, learning Razor is frustrating me as there is little documentation, and problems like these which should take minutes to resolve, are eating up way too much of my time.

Comment: I'm using MVC3 and just encountered this, what I think is a bug.

@{ Html.RenderPartial(...); } from the _Layout page does nothing.

If I use @Html.Partial(....) instead (ie, return a string and out put it, instead of using the RenderPartial method that writes directly to the response stream) I see the result of my Render Partial.

If I move the RenderPartial code to a controller's view (ie, not the _Layout page) then it works as expected.

So I think its a bug that you can't use RenderPartial() in the _Layout page.